# Selenium Python : StaleElementReferenceException when reading from file and using the word as search query

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My previous question was [Selenium Python - Access next pages of search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166689/selenium-python-access-next-pages-of-search-results)

After successfully doing this for one keyword, i need to read these keywords line by line from a file, and keep on searching.

```
file1 = open("M:/Users/Cyborg/Desktop/Py/read.txt","r")
```

the url is http://www.nice.org.uk/

```
driver.switch_to_default_content()
str2 = file1.readline()
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("searchText")
inputElement.clear()
inputElement.send_keys(str2)
```

this reads the keyword to be searched from the file, then enters it in the search box.

```
inputElement.submit()
```

submits the query. It's pretty much the same as in the question I asked before, and everything works perfectly if str2 is static, that is I define `str2='abc'` instead of reading from file. However as soon as I try to read from file and continue searching, I get this error

```
File "M:\Users\Cyborg\Desktop\Py\test.py", line 22, in <module>
    inputElement.submit()
  .
  .
  .
  .

 raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: 'Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up' ;
```

For some reason I get this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you entering values, submitting, then trying to enter more values, and submit again, still using `inputElement`?

Comment: Yes. What I need to do is enter value, submit, go through the search results, then enter another value, submit and repeat

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that after you perform `inputElement.submit()` once, the page is likely being refreshed, and at that point `inputElement` becomes stale.

I think getting a new reference for `inputElement` after each `inputElement.submit()` will clear it up:

```
inputElement.submit()
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_name("searchText")
```

Comment: I think i got it to work. Instead of after submit(), i referenced inputElement again after send_keys(). Thanks a lot!